# dummy value came out in C

Tags: c

```
typedef struct _node{
  int count;
  char * command;
  struct _node * next;
}Node;

typedef struct _list{
  Node * head;
  Node * cur;
  Node * tail;
}List;

List * history;

void list_init()
{
  history = (List*)malloc(sizeof(history));
  history->head = history->cur = history->tail = NULL;
}

char * copy_command(char * command, int len)
{
   char * temp_command = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
   strncpy(temp_command, command, len+1);
   return temp_command;
}

void insert_history(int cnt, char * command)
{
  Node * temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp->count = cnt;
  temp->command = command;
  temp->next = NULL;

  if(history->head == NULL){
    printf("hello %s\n", command);
    history->head = temp;
    printf("hello2 %s\n", temp->command);
  }
  else
    history->cur->next = temp;

  printf("head hello %s\n", history->head->command);
  history->cur = temp;
  history->tail = temp;
}


void print_history()
{
  history->cur = history->head;
  printf("history head: %s   | ", history->head->command);

  while(history->cur != NULL){
    printf("%-3d %s\n", history->cur->count, history->cur->command);
    history->cur = history->cur->next;
  }

  history->cur = history->tail;
}
```

Hi, all.
When I call this one,

```
char str[30] = "history";
list_init();
cur_command = copy_command(str, strlen(str))
insert_history(1, cur_command);
print_history();
```

I got

> hello history 
>       hello2 history 
>       head hello history 
>       history head: �&@��   | 1   �&@��

history is a global value which contains pointers to node.
It's okay when I print history->head->command in the insert_history() function,
but it's not okay when I print history->head->command in the print_history() function 
It's working as I expected when I call above code twice, 
but it doesn't work when I call it first time.
I don't know what should i do.

Comment: The question is missing several critical pieces of the puzzle. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Just as an aside, I would recommend replacing `temp->command = command` with `temp->command = copy_command(command, strlen(command))` That way, you don't need to remember to copy the string before calling the `insert_history` function. You can just call it with `insert_history(1, str)`.

Comment: Definitely need a [mcve]. I pasted your code into ideone - having to guess at a few things - and it worked. https://ideone.com/0pTvJQ

Comment: `history->head->command` is printed with no check that `history->head` is non-`NULL`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added some code of data structures and "list_init()" function. Sometimes above code worked and sometimes it didn't. I don't know why that happens together. I compiled it on GCC.

Comment: When I added the code that check whether history->head is NULL or not and print it if it is not NULL,  same result came out as I didn't add the code.

Comment: Looks like you're getting close to a complete example. Keep trying.

Comment: `history = (List*)malloc(sizeof(history));` This will only allocate `sizeof(List *)`. You want `malloc(sizeof(*history));` or `malloc(sizeof(List));`

Comment: Wow Thank you very much. I don't know why i couldn't find that..